# Right architecture for a partly shared realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm currently working on a Tinder-like app, where users get recommandations of other users, that are chosen by some algorithm. Each user will have it's own user specific realm, but this data will also be shared as the other users get this user as a recommandation. From what I have read, the shared realm will automatically get duplicated on the local devices of each user, which I definitely don't want.

So how can I now have a pool of users, but only share the calculated users by my algorithm to each user separately?

I have read some other threads about this topic also had a look into 'Designing a Database: Realm Threading Deep Dive', but at the moment I have no idea how to design my realm environment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the recommendation is to split the data into separate Realm files and move it between Realm files on the server in your own code.

We realize this is a bit cumbersome, and are currently working on better ways to achieve fine-grained sharing of data between users with object-level permissions. Stay tuned in the coming weeks and months.

Until then, duplicating the data into user-specific Realms is the best way forward.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, fine-grained sharing of data between users with object-level permissions would be exactly what we need.
Now we have decided to go on with the existing solution and create custom methods on the server layer to pass data between not synched realms. Is there any documentation for this? I have checked the object server doc, but such a special case is not listed. Since you know what our goal is, can you support us with the a little?